# Cannot combine commits using TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have two branches with several commits each. On one branch, I can go to the log, select two commits, and TortoiseGit shows "combine to one commit" in the context menu. On the other branch this option does not show in the context menu. Both sequence of commits is very similar; add file then modify it, so there is no difference really between the branches.

What factors would cause this "combine to one commit" to not be available? I'm wondering if I should just switch to the command line.

Comment: Is it possible that it's trying to protect you from combining "published" commits - are they already in origin on the branch where it doesn't let you?

Comment: Does it perhaps only work if you have the branch checked out? I think I see that condition in the code...

Comment: I'm skimming a lot, but it looks like they must be a sequence of consecutive commits on the current branch - it does the combining by hard-resetting the branch to the first commit, then mixed-resetting it to the last and committing, and then cherry-picking the rest on top.

Comment: You're correct, you must have the branch checked out. go ahead and answer this if you want some rep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have the branch checked out in order to combine commits using TortoiseGit.